# Ajuda com cadastro de produto com imagens

Tags: ionic, firebase, typescript, ionic3, firebase-database

Estou tentando fazer um cadastro de produtos, onde há possibilidade de ser cadastrado mais de uma foto por produto. Porém no service que criei, chamo um for para poder preencher a matriz de imagens, isso ocorre muito bem. Porém estou com uma dificuldade na lógica, para chamar a função save, por ela estar dentro do for, ela é chamada de acordo com o número de imagens que o usuário seleciona, se o usuário selecionar 2 imagens, ele cadastra dois produtos, se ele selecionar 3 imagens, cadastra 3 imagens e asssim por diante. Gostaria de uma ajuda para consertar este pequeno problema.

```
//esse é o meu service

        public uploadAndSave(item: any) {
        let produto = { $key: item.key,
                    nome: item.nome, 
                    url: [], 
                    fullPath: [],
                    preco: item.preco,
                    qtd: item.qtd, 
                    marca: item.marca,
                    tipo: item.tipo,
                    tamanho: item.tamanho,
                    cor: item.cor,
                    codigoBarras: item.codigoBarras
                  };

    if (produto.$key) {
      this.save(produto);
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < item.fileToUpload.length; i++){
        let storageRef = this.fb.storage().ref();
        let basePath = '/produtos/';
        produto.fullPath[i] = basePath + '/' + produto.nome + '.png';
        let uploadTask = storageRef.child(produto.fullPath[i]).putString(item.fileToUpload[i], 'base64');

        uploadTask.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        (snapshot) => {
          var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
          console.log(progress);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error(error);
        },
        () => {
          produto.url[i] = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
          this.save(produto);
        }); 
      }
    }
  }

//e aqui a minha chamada no meu arquivo ts : 

      //Cadastra o produto com foto
      cadastrarProduto() {
      this.produtosProvider.uploadAndSave({
          key: this.produtoKey,
          nome: this.produtoNome,
          tipo: this.produtoTipo,
          qtd: this.produtoQtd,
          tamanho: this.produtoTamanho,
          marca: this.produtoMarca,
          cor: this.produtoCor,
          preco: this.produtoPreco.replace(',','.'),
          fileToUpload: this.fileToUpload,
          codigoBarras: this.produtoCodigoBarras
       });
       this.toastCadastro();
       this.fechar();
      }
```

Comment: Pessoal, alguma ajuda com isso? Ainda não consegui resolver

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi bem seu problema, mas ao que parece você ta fazendo um **for**, que é um método sincrono e dentro dele disparando vários métodos assincronos, o que quer dizer que o **for** vai terminar e seguir antes dos uploads terminarem, se o que você quer é trazer esse código de upload para um modo "sincrono" pro **for** ficar esperando, você pode converter o observable em promisse e usar o async await, você vai "perder" o status do progresso nesse caso, mas acredito que o **for** vá esperar o upload nesse caso.

olha um exemplo de upload "assincrono" no firebase storage

```
async upload(file) {
    const fileName = `${new Date().getTime()}-${file.name}`;
    const filePath = `${this.PATH}/${fileName}`;
    const fileRef = this.afStorage.ref(filePath);
    await this.afStorage.upload(filePath, file).snapshotChanges().toPromise();
    const urlFile = await fileRef.getDownloadURL().toPromise();
    return { urlFile: urlFile, fileName: file.name };
  }
```

dentro do **for** ficaria assim:

```
for (let i = 0; i < item.fileToUpload.length; i++){
await upload(item.fileToUpload[i])
}
```